# 2 Javascripts not working with each other... (smooth scrolling & fade body)

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, fade

Dear stackoverflowers,

I have two javascript snippets that don't appear to be working properly together. 
The first one is there to fade out the body on an click event in the navigation, then redirect to a different page. But this appears to be working only after I clicked a link that triggers 'JavaScript-2'.

Here's the code for the first one:

```
// JavaScript-1
<script type="text/javascript">   
        $("a.transition").click(function(event){         
            event.preventDefault();                      
            linkLocation = this.href;
            $("body").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);      
        });

        function redirectPage() {
            window.location = linkLocation;
        }
</script>
```

'JavaScript-2' is the second one, that works together with 'jquery.easing.1.3.js' and produces nice smooth scrolling to an anchor. The scrolling always works fine and it fires in all situations.

I don't know why, but it looks like, that the smooth scrolling javascript causes the other javascript to fail.

I'm really looking forward to an answer to this little mystery.

Here's the code for the second one:

```
    // JavaScript-2 
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        $(function() {
            $('ul.navscroll a, #test a').bind('click',function(event){              
                var $anchor = $(this);

                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
                }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: W#hat do you mean by "causes it to fail"? What do you mean by "fail"?

Comment: Can it be that the `event.preventDefault();` in both click handlers cancel each out?

Comment: In my opinion the `JavaScript-1` does not work at all because of the missing `$(function () { ... });`

Comment: Both Javascripts work fine when they stand alone. 
But when I add 'Javascript-2' it causes, that somehow the 'JavaScript-1' does not fire it's event when I click a link on the navigation. But when I first click a link in the same nav that triggers to scroll to an anchor and then click the link that should fire the body to fade and redirect to a different URL, it works.

Comment: Why do you have two javascript files? Just combine the two scripts and wrap all of it within a `$(document).ready(function(){ ...Javascript-1 and 2... });`

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your `Javascript-1` code like this:

```
// JavaScript-1
<script type="text/javascript">   
   $(function() { // this fires the jQuery after load
        var linkLocation = false; // define the linkLocation var

        $("a.transition").click(function(event){         
            event.preventDefault();                      
            linkLocation = this.href;
            $("body").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);      
        });

        function redirectPage() {
            window.location = linkLocation;
        }
   });
</script>
```

There are 2 main things corrected here:

1. `$(function() {...});` will fire the jQuery-Events after the DOM is completely loaded
2. `var linkLocation` must be defined before you access on them in the `redirectPage()`-Method

For removing the error in `Javascript-2` (where it breaks the Javascript) update them like this:

```
// JavaScript-2 
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(function() {
        $('ul.navscroll a, #test a').bind('click',function(event){              
            target = $(this).attr('href'); // find the top of the target
            offset = $(target).offset(); // this returns an object {top: y,left: x}
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: offset.top
            }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now if you click on a link with `href='#test'` you will scroll to the element with the ID test for example your `<footer id='test'>`.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work either. Causes the same problem like before.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to just use one event.preventDefault(); and merge both scripts? If yes, I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: Yes, I see an error there. He tells me that "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined", which is in 'JavaScript-2', which appears to work fine anyway.

Comment: So this error is the reason why it breaks there and does not execute the following scripts. My update should solve this problem in Javascript-2

Comment: In FF he tells me the following when I click on a link that should be working, but isn't. 
--
    TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined

Comment: This somehow solves the error in the console but causes some wired scrolling and doesn't appear to solve the problem. If you want to see for yourself, I welcome you to take a quick look at my page. [Click here for my website www.designlike.de/c_website_test/index.htm](http://designlike.de/c_website_test/index.htm)

Comment: @Dennis Schröder: Updated: Now if you have an anchor calling test it scrolls to the <div id='test'>. Make sure you have this DIVs available in the DOM you refer in the navigation. So the "Contact"-Link should go on "#test" that it works fine.

Comment: Still doesn't work here. I updated it also on my weblink. It still causes, that I first have to click in the navigation in the top right corner on 'contact' and only after it scrolled down and I then click on 'work' it works. Now it also produces the same console error like before... Do you have any idea?

Comment: It looks like from what I can see in the console while clicking, that when I click on work it refers to JavaScript-2, instead of firing the body to fade.

Comment: No working answer so far. Maybe anyone with a different idea?